# jQuery not working on PhoneGap

Tags: jquery, html, cordova

I have been coding with jQuery, JavaScript, Ajax and PHP, and when I want to create my app using PhoneGap, jQuery nor CSS scripts are not working. Some idea?

My code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/template01.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/own.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../jqm/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.min.css" />

<script src="../jqm/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/register.js"></script>
<script src="../js/volcap.js"></script>
<script src="../js/volser.js"></script>
<script src="../js/verser.js"></script>
```

Comment: Are you using jQuery mobile also?

Comment: I said jQuery but I mean jQuery mobile, yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem with [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) version.Use only following [CDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) :

```
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Comment: Finaly!! Using that CDN my app is working, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I happen to be building an app in phonegap as we speak and jQuery works perfectly fine for me. If you copy your phonegap structure to any folder as if it's any other HTML website, it should work fine. (This is also how I build any html to a Phonegap project)

Doing this should make it clear to you where the issue is. I am going to guess it's something to do with your way of including. Are you entirely sure the `href` and `src` attributes are filled in correctly?

Your index.html should be in the very root of your project with phonegap. Can you give us more insight into your map structure?

For me, in my project, it looks like this:

```
<script src="assets/plugins/jquery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/plugins/abtags/ab.tags.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/init.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/marketplace.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/stores.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/catalog.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/tracking.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
<script>init();</script>
```

And this works perfectly fine. Considering that **index.html has to be in the root directory of your project**, I cannot imagine you needing `../` in your directories, since it would go back one level too deep.

**Edit:** Also not entirely unimportant: Are you using Phonegap Build, or CLI?

If you are using the CLI, note that there's a special place for css files and js files.

> While Cordova allows you to easily deploy an app for many different platforms, sometimes you need to add customizations. In that case, you don't want to modify the source files in various www directories within the top-level platforms directory, because they're regularly replaced with the top-level www directory's cross-platform source.

example:
Put your css file in `www/css/index.css`.
link it like this: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/overrides.css" />`

Source here: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/ (search `for using merges to customize each platform`)

Comment: You are right, I don't need the "../", I has copied the code from another html I was coding at same time, also it's not working for me. I am using de CLI. Thanks

Comment: No problem. Please don't forget to accept the answer if it's to your satisfaction, so people know the matter has been closed :) -- I thought you meant it's not working for you in the other html file also, but you mean it's still not working even after removing `../`?

Comment: It's still not working, yes. I tryed other things I read over here, but nothing works :(

Comment: Are you sure the scripts are getting included? Can you place an alert in your html file to test that your file even updates correctly? And if that works, put one on top of your javascript file to test it once more? Are you actually initialising the app? Did you properly include `cordova.js?`

Comment: It could be because I have not included de cordova.js file? I have not read about it previously... I tested the js files with alerts and jquery file and mines are working, but it is not doing the "page-rol" I have coded.